# How to calculate only latest candle on a screener script

Tags: pine-script

I have following pine script which returns two buy points using a yellow shape.arrowdown (BUY)
and a lime arrow

```
study("SniperVX", overlay=true, shorttitle="Vdub_SniperBX_v1")

slow = 8
fast = 5
vh1 = ema(highest(avg(low, close), fast), 5)
vl1 = ema(lowest(avg(high, close), slow), 8)
//
e_ema1 = ema(close, 1)
e_ema2 = ema(e_ema1, 1)
e_ema3 = ema(e_ema2, 1)
tema = 1 * (e_ema1 - e_ema2) + e_ema3
//
e_e1 = ema(close, 8)
e_e2 = ema(e_e1, 5)
dema = 2 * e_e1 - e_e2
signal = tema > dema ? max(vh1, vl1) : min(vh1, vl1)
is_call = tema > dema and signal > low and (signal-signal[1] > signal[1]-signal[2])
is_put = tema < dema and signal < high and (signal[1]-signal > signal[2]-signal[1])
 

//plotshape(is_put ? -1 : na, title="SELL ARROW", color=red, text="*SELL*", style=shape.arrowdown)
//
//Modified - Rajandran R Supertrend----------------------------------------------------- //       Signal 2

Factor=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 000, title="Trend Transition Signal")
Pd=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))
TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn
Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],0)
 
plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=lime, maxheight=1000, minheight=50, transp=85)
plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=red, maxheight=1000, minheight=50, transp=85)
plotshape(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 and is_call ? 1 : na, title="BUY ARROW", color=yellow, text="BUY", style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 and is_put ? -1 : na, title="SELL ARROW", color=red, text="SELL", style=shape.arrowdown, location=location.abovebar)
```

I'm trying to convert it to a screener and I'm using this code to screen 40 stocks

```
//@version=4
study("Help (Screener)", overlay=false)

// blocco 2
s1 = input('MIL:PIA', type=input.symbol)
s2 = input('MIL:BST', type=input.symbol)
s3 = input('MIL:MONC', type=input.symbol)
s4 = input('MIL:AMP', type=input.symbol)
s5 = input('MIL:TGYM', type=input.symbol)
s6 = input('MIL:BZU', type=input.symbol)
s7 = input('MIL:LR', type=input.symbol)
s8 = input('MIL:CVAL', type=input.symbol)
s9 = input('MIL:PRO', type=input.symbol)
s10 = input('MIL:RM', type=input.symbol)
s11 = input('MIL:CASS', type=input.symbol)
s12 = input('MIL:LIT', type=input.symbol)
s13 = input('MIL:BRE', type=input.symbol)
s14 = input('MIL:TFI', type=input.symbol)
s15 = input('MIL:PRL', type=input.symbol)
s16 = input('MIL:EXO', type=input.symbol)
s17 = input('MIL:GAB', type=input.symbol)
s18 = input('MIL:IKG', type=input.symbol)
s19 = input('MIL:PRT', type=input.symbol)
s20 = input('MIL:IMS', type=input.symbol)
s21 = input('MIL:IGD', type=input.symbol)
s22 = input('MIL:BGN', type=input.symbol)
s23 = input('MIL:MTV', type=input.symbol)
s24 = input('MIL:UNIR', type=input.symbol)
s25 = input('MIL:CAI', type=input.symbol)
s26 = input('MIL:SCK', type=input.symbol)
s27 = input('MIL:AEF', type=input.symbol)
s28 = input('MIL:MN', type=input.symbol)
s29 = input('MIL:IP', type=input.symbol)
s30 = input('MIL:CE', type=input.symbol)
s31 = input('MIL:FNM', type=input.symbol)
s32 = input('MIL:RWAY', type=input.symbol)
s33 = input('MIL:RCS', type=input.symbol)
s34 = input('MIL:BEST', type=input.symbol)
s35 = input('MIL:ERG', type=input.symbol)
s36 = input('MIL:EM', type=input.symbol)
s37 = input('MIL:TNXT', type=input.symbol)
s38 = input('MIL:BFE', type=input.symbol)
s39 = input('MIL:MARR', type=input.symbol)
s40 = input('MIL:GVS', type=input.symbol)




///////////////
// FUNCTIONS //


var Factor=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 000, title="Trend Transition Signal")
var Pd=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 100)
slow = 8
fast = 5
vh1 = ema(highest(avg(low, close), fast), 5)
vl1 = ema(lowest(avg(high, close), slow), 8)
e_ema1 = ema(close, 1)
e_ema2 = ema(e_ema1, 1)
e_ema3 = ema(e_ema2, 1)
tema = 1 * (e_ema1 - e_ema2) + e_ema3
//
e_e1 = ema(close, 8)
e_e2 = ema(e_e1, 5)
dema = 2 * e_e1 - e_e2
signal = tema > dema ? max(vh1, vl1) : min(vh1, vl1)
is_call = tema > dema and signal > low and (signal-signal[1] > signal[1]-signal[2])
is_put = tema < dema and signal < high and (signal[1]-signal > signal[2]-signal[1])


// Screener Function
screenerFunc() => 

    Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
    Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))    

    TrendUp = 0.0
    TrendDown = 0.0
    Trend = 0

    TrendUp :=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
    TrendDown :=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn
    Trend := close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],0)
    cond = Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 and is_call
    [Trend, cond]
    
    
// Rounding Function
roundn(x, n) => 
    mult_local = 1 
    if n != 0
        for i = 1 to abs(n)
            mult_local := mult_local * 10
    
    n >= 0 ? round(x * mult_local) / mult_local : round(x / mult_local) * mult_local 

///////////////////////////////////////
// Running Functions for all sybmols //

[v1, c1] = security(s1, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v2, c2] = security(s2, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v3, c3] = security(s3, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v4, c4] = security(s4, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v5, c5] = security(s5, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v6, c6] = security(s6, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v7, c7] = security(s7, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v8, c8] = security(s8, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v9, c9] = security(s9, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v10, c10] = security(s10, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v11, c11] = security(s11, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v12, c12] = security(s12, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v13, c13] = security(s13, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v14, c14] = security(s14, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v15, c15] = security(s15, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v16, c16] = security(s16, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v17, c17] = security(s17, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v18, c18] = security(s18, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v19, c19] = security(s19, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v20, c20] = security(s20, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v21, c21] = security(s21, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v22, c22] = security(s22, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v23, c23] = security(s23, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v24, c24] = security(s24, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v25, c25] = security(s25, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v26, c26] = security(s26, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v27, c27] = security(s27, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v28, c28] = security(s28, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v29, c29] = security(s29, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v30, c30] = security(s30, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v31, c31] = security(s31, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v32, c32] = security(s32, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v33, c33] = security(s33, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v34, c34] = security(s34, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v35, c35] = security(s35, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v36, c36] = security(s36, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v37, c37] = security(s37, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v38, c38] = security(s38, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v39, c39] = security(s39, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v40, c40] = security(s40, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())

////////////////////
// Screener label //

f_buildLabel(_c, _s, _v) =>
    _c ? _s + ' ' + tostring(roundn(_v, 3)) + ' :: ' : ''
    
if barstate.islast
    scr_label = ''
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c1, s1, v1)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c2, s2, v2)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c3, s3, v3)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c4, s4, v4)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c5, s5, v5)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c6, s6, v6)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c7, s7, v7)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c8, s8, v8)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c9, s9, v9)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c10, s10, v10)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c11, s11, v11)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c12, s12, v12)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c13, s13, v13)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c14, s14, v14)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c15, s15, v15)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c16, s16, v16)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c17, s17, v17)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c18, s18, v18)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c19, s19, v19)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c20, s20, v20)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c21, s21, v21)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c22, s22, v22)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c23, s23, v23)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c24, s24, v24)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c25, s25, v25)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c26, s26, v26)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c27, s27, v27)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c28, s28, v28)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c29, s29, v29)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c30, s30, v30)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c31, s31, v31)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c32, s32, v32)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c33, s33, v33)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c34, s34, v34)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c35, s35, v35)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c36, s36, v36)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c37, s37, v37)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c38, s38, v38)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c39, s39, v39)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c40, s40, v40)

    
    
    scr_label := scr_label + "" 
    
   
    
    // Plot Label
    lab_l = label.new(
              bar_index, 0, scr_label, 
              color=color.green, 
              textcolor=color.white, 
              style =  label.style_labeldown,
              yloc = yloc.price)
```

But it does not work as I want, because I want receive as result only stocks that have a yellow shape.arrowdown (BUY) AND a lime arrow **ONLY** in the latest candle of the chart.
( Currently the screneer returns stocks which have a yellow shape.arrowdown (BUY) AND a lime arrow
also 10 or more candles ago ).  How to do this ?

Comment: Please write on which ticker on which timeframe this error occurs.

Comment: I execute the search using daily timeframe. Please wait I will report you the error

Comment: e.g. add the ticker MIL:ITW in the s1 section instead of MIL:PIA . You will receive this  https://www.tradingview.com/x/gRFpFAGr/  , as you can see the result is not in the latest candle.

Comment: The function `security` by default refers to regular candlesticks, and your chart is based on heiken ashi candlesticks therefore, the results are different. switch to regular candlesticks and check the signals on the ticker MIL:ITW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version of the script for Heiken Ashi candles. Also fixed the function `screenerFunc`.

IMPORTANT! The running time of the script may go beyond the set limit.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (Screener) for HA", overlay=false)

// blocco 2
s1 = input('MIL:ITW', type=input.symbol)
s2 = input('MIL:BST', type=input.symbol)
s3 = input('MIL:MONC', type=input.symbol)
s4 = input('MIL:AMP', type=input.symbol)
s5 = input('MIL:TGYM', type=input.symbol)
s6 = input('MIL:BZU', type=input.symbol)
s7 = input('MIL:LR', type=input.symbol)
s8 = input('MIL:CVAL', type=input.symbol)
s9 = input('MIL:PRO', type=input.symbol)
s10 = input('MIL:RM', type=input.symbol)
s11 = input('MIL:CASS', type=input.symbol)
s12 = input('MIL:LIT', type=input.symbol)
s13 = input('MIL:BRE', type=input.symbol)
s14 = input('MIL:TFI', type=input.symbol)
s15 = input('MIL:PRL', type=input.symbol)
s16 = input('MIL:EXO', type=input.symbol)
s17 = input('MIL:GAB', type=input.symbol)
s18 = input('MIL:IKG', type=input.symbol)
s19 = input('MIL:PRT', type=input.symbol)
s20 = input('MIL:IMS', type=input.symbol)
s21 = input('MIL:IGD', type=input.symbol)
s22 = input('MIL:BGN', type=input.symbol)
s23 = input('MIL:MTV', type=input.symbol)
s24 = input('MIL:UNIR', type=input.symbol)
s25 = input('MIL:CAI', type=input.symbol)
s26 = input('MIL:SCK', type=input.symbol)
s27 = input('MIL:AEF', type=input.symbol)
s28 = input('MIL:MN', type=input.symbol)
s29 = input('MIL:IP', type=input.symbol)
s30 = input('MIL:CE', type=input.symbol)
s31 = input('MIL:FNM', type=input.symbol)
s32 = input('MIL:RWAY', type=input.symbol)
s33 = input('MIL:RCS', type=input.symbol)
s34 = input('MIL:BEST', type=input.symbol)
s35 = input('MIL:ERG', type=input.symbol)
s36 = input('MIL:EM', type=input.symbol)
s37 = input('MIL:TNXT', type=input.symbol)
s38 = input('MIL:BFE', type=input.symbol)
s39 = input('MIL:MARR', type=input.symbol)
s40 = input('MIL:GVS', type=input.symbol)




///////////////
// FUNCTIONS //


var Factor=input(1, minval=1, maxval = 9, title="Trend Transition Signal")
var Pd=input(1, minval=1, maxval = 9)

// Screener Function
screenerFunc() => 
    
    slow = 8
    fast = 5
    vh1 = ema(highest(avg(low, close), fast), 5)
    vl1 = ema(lowest(avg(high, close), slow), 8)
    e_ema1 = ema(close, 1)
    e_ema2 = ema(e_ema1, 1)
    e_ema3 = ema(e_ema2, 1)
    tema = 1 * (e_ema1 - e_ema2) + e_ema3
    //
    e_e1 = ema(close, 8)
    e_e2 = ema(e_e1, 5)
    dema = 2 * e_e1 - e_e2
    signal = tema > dema ? max(vh1, vl1) : min(vh1, vl1)
    is_call = tema > dema and signal > low and (signal-signal[1] > signal[1]-signal[2])
    is_put = tema < dema and signal < high and (signal[1]-signal > signal[2]-signal[1])

    Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
    Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))    

    TrendUp = 0.0
    TrendDown = 0.0
    Trend = 0

    TrendUp :=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
    TrendDown :=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn
    Trend := close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],0)
    cond = Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 and is_call
    [Trend, cond]
    
    
// Rounding Function
roundn(x, n) => 
    mult_local = 1 
    if n != 0
        for i = 1 to abs(n)
            mult_local := mult_local * 10
    
    n >= 0 ? round(x * mult_local) / mult_local : round(x / mult_local) * mult_local 

///////////////////////////////////////
// Running Functions for all sybmols //

[v1, c1] = security(heikinashi(s1), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v2, c2] = security(heikinashi(s2), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v3, c3] = security(heikinashi(s3), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v4, c4] = security(heikinashi(s4), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v5, c5] = security(heikinashi(s5), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v6, c6] = security(heikinashi(s6), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v7, c7] = security(heikinashi(s7), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v8, c8] = security(heikinashi(s8), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v9, c9] = security(heikinashi(s9), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v10, c10] = security(heikinashi(s10), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v11, c11] = security(heikinashi(s11), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v12, c12] = security(heikinashi(s12), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v13, c13] = security(heikinashi(s13), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v14, c14] = security(heikinashi(s14), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v15, c15] = security(heikinashi(s15), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v16, c16] = security(heikinashi(s16), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v17, c17] = security(heikinashi(s17), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v18, c18] = security(heikinashi(s18), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v19, c19] = security(heikinashi(s19), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v20, c20] = security(heikinashi(s20), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v21, c21] = security(heikinashi(s21), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v22, c22] = security(heikinashi(s22), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v23, c23] = security(heikinashi(s23), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v24, c24] = security(heikinashi(s24), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v25, c25] = security(heikinashi(s25), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v26, c26] = security(heikinashi(s26), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v27, c27] = security(heikinashi(s27), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v28, c28] = security(heikinashi(s28), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v29, c29] = security(heikinashi(s29), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v30, c30] = security(heikinashi(s30), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v31, c31] = security(heikinashi(s31), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v32, c32] = security(heikinashi(s32), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v33, c33] = security(heikinashi(s33), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v34, c34] = security(heikinashi(s34), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v35, c35] = security(heikinashi(s35), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v36, c36] = security(heikinashi(s36), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v37, c37] = security(heikinashi(s37), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v38, c38] = security(heikinashi(s38), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v39, c39] = security(heikinashi(s39), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v40, c40] = security(heikinashi(s40), timeframe.period, screenerFunc())

////////////////////
// Screener label //

f_buildLabel(_c, _s, _v) =>
    _c ? _s + ' ' + tostring(roundn(_v, 3)) + ' :: ' : ''
    
if barstate.islast
    scr_label = ''
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c1, s1, v1)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c2, s2, v2)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c3, s3, v3)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c4, s4, v4)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c5, s5, v5)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c6, s6, v6)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c7, s7, v7)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c8, s8, v8)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c9, s9, v9)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c10, s10, v10)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c11, s11, v11)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c12, s12, v12)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c13, s13, v13)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c14, s14, v14)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c15, s15, v15)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c16, s16, v16)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c17, s17, v17)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c18, s18, v18)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c19, s19, v19)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c20, s20, v20)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c21, s21, v21)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c22, s22, v22)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c23, s23, v23)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c24, s24, v24)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c25, s25, v25)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c26, s26, v26)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c27, s27, v27)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c28, s28, v28)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c29, s29, v29)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c30, s30, v30)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c31, s31, v31)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c32, s32, v32)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c33, s33, v33)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c34, s34, v34)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c35, s35, v35)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c36, s36, v36)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c37, s37, v37)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c38, s38, v38)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c39, s39, v39)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c40, s40, v40)

    
    
    scr_label := scr_label + "" 
    
   
    
    // Plot Label
    lab_l = label.new(
              bar_index, 0, scr_label, 
              color=color.green, 
              textcolor=color.white, 
              style =  label.style_labeldown,
              yloc = yloc.price)
```

Comment: Thank you , can I use also with heiken ashi candlesticks or only with regular candles ?

Comment: This version of the script is only for heiken ashi candles.

Comment: fantastic thank you, last question please , since I have 160 stocks to analyze do you know if there are alternative ways to bypass the 40 stocks limits for the screener ?

Comment: Alternatively, you can display this indicator four times each time for the new forty tickers. You can also make four versions of the indicator, each of which has its own tickers.

Comment: sorry I forgot to send you the bounty , I sent now.