# Assistance with Function to create Screener

Tags: pine-script

Afternoon all,

I am currently using the below script to monitor the highest and lowest Initial Balances for 3 market openings. Currently I switch between the symbols to see if price action has gone above the highest or lowest IB.

https://uk.tradingview.com/script/LoAJFXlT-Initial-Balance-Markets-Time-Zones-Overall-Highest-and-Lowest/

My idea I would like to put into code is to have a screener that allows me to view 10-20 symbols. Which would show green, red or white. Green if that symbols price action has gone above the highest IB, red below lowest IB, white if in between.

Similar to:
https://uk.tradingview.com/script/La1XGzDj-Supertrend-Screener-Panel/

Currently the code is repeated with the only difference being time input for the three markets.

As the same code/processes will be repeated for each symbol I believe it could be made into a function where:

1. If price action is above all IBs = 1 = green
2. If price action is below all IBs = -1 = red
3. If price action is neither of above = 0 = white

Any guidance would be gratefully appreciated:

Code below is extracted from the IB script above:

```
time_int_01 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)    
in_time_int_01 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_01)    
var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 10e10
if in_time_int_01
    if not in_time_int_01[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance Asia Finish

//////////////////////////////////// Asia Plot Start
//High
AsiaIBHighInput = input('0100-0101:1234567', title="Capture Asia IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in

AsiaIBHigh = time("1", AsiaIBHighInput)

var AsiaIBHighPA = 0.0
if AsiaIBHigh
    if not AsiaIBHigh[1]
        AsiaIBHighPA := highe_01

plotAsiaIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBHighPA : na, title=" Asia IB High", color=color.purple, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia IB High")

//Low
AsiaIBLowInput = input('0100-0101:1234567', title="Capture Asia IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in

AsiaIBLow = time("1", AsiaIBLowInput)

var AsiaIBLowPA = 0.0
if AsiaIBLow
    if not AsiaIBLow[1]
        AsiaIBLowPA := lowe_01

plotAsiaIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBLowPA : na, title=" Asia IB Low", color=color.purple, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia IB Low")
//////////////////////////////////// Asia Plot Finish
// Asia FINISH //



// London START //
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance London Start
time_int_02 = input("0800-0900:1234567", "London IB Range", input.session)

in_time_int_02 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_02)

var highe_02 = 0.0
var lowe_02  = 10e10
if in_time_int_02
    if not in_time_int_02[1]
        highe_02 := high
        lowe_02  := low
    else
        highe_02 := max(high, highe_02)
        lowe_02  := min(low, lowe_02)
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance London Finsh

//////////////////////////////////// London Plot Start
//High
LonIBHighInput = input('0900-0901:1234567', title="Capture London IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in

LonIBHigh = time("1", LonIBHighInput)

var LonIBHighPA = 0.0
if LonIBHigh
    if not LonIBHigh[1]
        LonIBHighPA := highe_02

plotLonIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBHighPA : na, title=" Lon IB High", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Lon IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Lon IB High")

//Low
LonIBLowInput = input('0900-0901:1234567', title="Capture London IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in

LonIBLow = time("1", LonIBLowInput)

var LonIBLowPA = 0.0
if LonIBLow
    if not LonIBLow[1]
        LonIBLowPA := lowe_02

plotLonIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBLowPA : na, title=" Lon IB Low", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Lon IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Lon IB Low")
//////////////////////////////////// London Plot Finish
// London FINISH //



// New York START //
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance New York Start
time_int_03 = input("1430-1530:1234567", "New York IB Range", input.session)

in_time_int_03 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_03)

var highe_03 = 0.0
var lowe_03  = 10e10
if in_time_int_03
    if not in_time_int_03[1]
        highe_03 := high
        lowe_03  := low
    else
        highe_03 := max(high, highe_03)
        lowe_03  := min(low, lowe_03)
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance New York Finish

//////////////////////////////////// New York Plot Start
//High
NYIBHighInput = input('1530-1531:1234567', title="Capture New York IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in

NYIBHigh = time("1", NYIBHighInput)

var NYIBHighPA = 0.0
if NYIBHigh
    if not NYIBHigh[1]
        NYIBHighPA := highe_03

plotNYIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBHighPA : na, title=" New York IB High", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York IB High")

//Low
NYIBLowInput = input('1530-1531:1234567', title="Capture New York IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in

NYIBLow = time("1", NYIBLowInput)

var NYIBLowPA = 0.0
if NYIBLow
    if not NYIBLow[1]
        NYIBLowPA := lowe_03

plotNYIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBLowPA : na, title=" New York IB Low", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York IB Low")
//////////////////////////////////// New York Plot Finish
// New York FINISH //


// Background colors
AsiaAboveHigh = close>(AsiaIBHighPA)
LondonAboveHigh = close>(LonIBHighPA)
NewYorkAboveHigh = close>(NYIBHighPA)

// IB Highest and Lowest Settings
Buy = AsiaAboveHigh and LondonAboveHigh and NewYorkAboveHigh
bgcolor(Buy and backcolor ? color.green : na, transp=95, title='Check Chart Buy Signal above all IB Highs')

AsiaBelowLow = close<(AsiaIBLowPA)
LondonBelowLow = close<(LonIBLowPA)
NewYorkBelowLow = close<(NYIBLowPA)

Sell = AsiaBelowLow and LondonBelowLow and NewYorkBelowLow
bgcolor(Sell and backcolor ? color.red : na, transp=95, title='Check Chart Sell Signal below all IB Lows')
```

#####################################################################
Update 08/03/2021 - 1700 for @AnyDozer

Below is script so far I have put a simple function in so it doesn't error, Any assistance will be gratefully appreciated. I have been trying to develop the function but have not been successful.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Panel Wave Trend & MF", shorttitle="Panel Wave Trend & MF")

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// USER Symbol Input

Symbol01 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:BTCUSD")
Symbol02 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:LTCUSD")
Symbol03 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:BCHUSD")
Symbol04 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:ETHUSD")
Symbol05 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:CGLDUSD")
Symbol06 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:ALGOUSD")

// User adjustment inputs
offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=20)
backcolor = input(true, title="Optional background colour Price Action (PA) above or below all IB highs/lows")
DisplayAllIBs = input(false, title="Optional to display all IB highs/lows")
MidLinebackcolor = input(false, title="Optional background colour Price Action (PA) above or below all Midline")

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//TRYING TO IMPLEMENT THE BELOW IB PROCESSES INTO A FUNCTION SO THAT IT CAN USED ACROSS SEVERAL SYMBOLS IN A SCREENER
//The below works out the Initial Balance for Asia, London and New York then plots from the time the IB has finshed its 60 mins.
//It then looks at the 3 IBs to see which IB is the highest and plots it.
//The aim is to plot green on the monitoring panel if the price has gone above the highest IB
//Plot red if price has gone below the lowest IB
//Plot white if it is inbetween the highest and lowest IB


// Asia START //
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance Asia Start
time_int_01 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)

in_time_int_01 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_01)

var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 10e10
if in_time_int_01
    if not in_time_int_01[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance Asia Finish

//////////////////////////////////// Asia Plot Start
//High
AsiaIBHighInput = input('0100-0101:1234567', title="Capture Asia IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in

AsiaIBHigh = time("1", AsiaIBHighInput)

var AsiaIBHighPA = 0.0
if AsiaIBHigh
    if not AsiaIBHigh[1]
        AsiaIBHighPA := highe_01

plotAsiaIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBHighPA : na, title=" Asia IB High", color=color.purple, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia IB High")

//Low
AsiaIBLowInput = input('0100-0101:1234567', title="Capture Asia IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in

AsiaIBLow = time("1", AsiaIBLowInput)

var AsiaIBLowPA = 0.0
if AsiaIBLow
    if not AsiaIBLow[1]
        AsiaIBLowPA := lowe_01

plotAsiaIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBLowPA : na, title=" Asia IB Low", color=color.purple, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia IB Low")
//////////////////////////////////// Asia Plot Finish
// Asia FINISH //



// London START //
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance London Start
time_int_02 = input("0800-0900:1234567", "London IB Range", input.session)

in_time_int_02 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_02)

var highe_02 = 0.0
var lowe_02  = 10e10
if in_time_int_02
    if not in_time_int_02[1]
        highe_02 := high
        lowe_02  := low
    else
        highe_02 := max(high, highe_02)
        lowe_02  := min(low, lowe_02)
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance London Finsh

//////////////////////////////////// London Plot Start
//High
LonIBHighInput = input('0900-0901:1234567', title="Capture London IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in

LonIBHigh = time("1", LonIBHighInput)

var LonIBHighPA = 0.0
if LonIBHigh
    if not LonIBHigh[1]
        LonIBHighPA := highe_02

plotLonIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBHighPA : na, title=" Lon IB High", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Lon IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Lon IB High")

//Low
LonIBLowInput = input('0900-0901:1234567', title="Capture London IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in

LonIBLow = time("1", LonIBLowInput)

var LonIBLowPA = 0.0
if LonIBLow
    if not LonIBLow[1]
        LonIBLowPA := lowe_02

plotLonIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBLowPA : na, title=" Lon IB Low", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Lon IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Lon IB Low")
//////////////////////////////////// London Plot Finish
// London FINISH //



// New York START //
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance New York Start
time_int_03 = input("1430-1530:1234567", "New York IB Range", input.session)

in_time_int_03 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_03)

var highe_03 = 0.0
var lowe_03  = 10e10
if in_time_int_03
    if not in_time_int_03[1]
        highe_03 := high
        lowe_03  := low
    else
        highe_03 := max(high, highe_03)
        lowe_03  := min(low, lowe_03)
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance New York Finish

//////////////////////////////////// New York Plot Start
//High
NYIBHighInput = input('1530-1531:1234567', title="Capture New York IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in

NYIBHigh = time("1", NYIBHighInput)

var NYIBHighPA = 0.0
if NYIBHigh
    if not NYIBHigh[1]
        NYIBHighPA := highe_03

plotNYIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBHighPA : na, title=" New York IB High", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York IB High")

//Low
NYIBLowInput = input('1530-1531:1234567', title="Capture New York IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in

NYIBLow = time("1", NYIBLowInput)

var NYIBLowPA = 0.0
if NYIBLow
    if not NYIBLow[1]
        NYIBLowPA := lowe_03

plotNYIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBLowPA : na, title=" New York IB Low", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York IB Low")
//////////////////////////////////// New York Plot Finish
// New York FINISH //


// Background colors
AsiaAboveHigh = close>(AsiaIBHighPA)
LondonAboveHigh = close>(LonIBHighPA)
NewYorkAboveHigh = close>(NYIBHighPA)

// IB Highest and Lowest Settings
Buy = AsiaAboveHigh and LondonAboveHigh and NewYorkAboveHigh
bgcolor(Buy and backcolor ? color.green : na, transp=95, title='Check Chart Buy Signal above all IB Highs')

AsiaBelowLow = close<(AsiaIBLowPA)
LondonBelowLow = close<(LonIBLowPA)
NewYorkBelowLow = close<(NYIBLowPA)

Sell = AsiaBelowLow and LondonBelowLow and NewYorkBelowLow
bgcolor(Sell and backcolor ? color.red : na, transp=95, title='Check Chart Sell Signal below all IB Lows')



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//TRYING TO IMPLEMENT THE ABOVE IB PROCESSES INTO A FUNCTION SO THAT IT CAN USED ACROSS SEVERAL SYMBOLS IN A SCREENER
//The below works out the Initial Balance for Asia, London and New York then plots from the time the IB has finshed its 60 mins.
//It then looks at the 3 IBs to see which IB is the highest and plots it.
//The aim is to plot green on the monitoring panel if the price has gone above the highest IB
//Plot red if price has gone below the lowest IB
//Plot white if it is inbetween the highest and lowest IB


IBCALC () =>

//    AsiaIBTime = input('0000-0100:1234567')
//    var highe_A = 0.0
//    var lowe_A  = 10e10
//    if AsiaIBTime
//        if not AsiaIBTime[1]
//            highe_A := high
//            lowe_A  := low
//        else
//            highe_A := max(high, highe_A)
//            lowe_A  := min(low, lowe_A)




    AboveAllIBs = color.green //#0CAB07 // Dark Green  -> Long
    BelowAllIBs = color.red //#DE071C // Dark Red    -> Short
    InBetween   = color.white //#E1DE14 // Yellow      #000000   #555555
    
    
    C   = close
    O   = open
    

    IBcolor_  = C > O ? C > C[1] ? AboveAllIBs : AboveAllIBs : C < O ? C < C[1] ? BelowAllIBs : BelowAllIBs : InBetween


    [IBcolor_]


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

[IBcolor_] = IBCALC ()

color_Sym01 = security(Symbol01, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)
color_Sym02 = security(Symbol02, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)
color_Sym03 = security(Symbol03, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)
color_Sym04 = security(Symbol04, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)
color_Sym05 = security(Symbol05, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)
color_Sym06 = security(Symbol06, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)

// === PLOT HISTOGRAM ===

// === Allocate Strategies to Lines ===
Sym01_bar = 6
Sym02_bar = 5
Sym03_bar = 4
Sym04_bar = 3
Sym05_bar = 2
Sym06_bar = 1


// === Plot Signals per Strategy ===
plot(Sym01_bar, title="BTCUSD", color = color_Sym01, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)
plot(Sym02_bar, title="LTCUSD", color = color_Sym02, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)
plot(Sym03_bar, title="BCHUSD", color = color_Sym03, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)
plot(Sym04_bar, title="ETHUSD", color = color_Sym04, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)
plot(Sym05_bar, title="CGLDUSD", color = color_Sym05, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)
plot(Sym06_bar, title="ALGOUSD", color = color_Sym06, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)


// === Plot Background lines ===
line0 = hline(0, title="Line 0", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line1 = hline(1, title="Line 1", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line2 = hline(2, title="Line 2", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line3 = hline(3, title="Line 3", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line4 = hline(4, title="Line 4", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line5 = hline(5, title="Line 5", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line6 = hline(6, title="Line 6", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)


// === Plot Labels ===
chper = time - time[1]
chper := change(chper) > 0 ? chper[1] : chper

var label l_Sym01 = na, var label l_Sym02 = na, var label l_Sym03 = na, var label l_Sym04 = na, var label l_Sym05 = na, var label l_Sym06 = na
label.delete(l_Sym01), label.delete(l_Sym02), label.delete(l_Sym03), label.delete(l_Sym04), label.delete(l_Sym05), label.delete(l_Sym06)

l_Sym01 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym01_bar-1, text = "BTCUSD",   textcolor=#FFFFFF, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
l_Sym02 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym02_bar-1, text = "LTCUSD",   textcolor=#FFFFFF, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
l_Sym03 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym03_bar-1, text = "BCHUSD",   textcolor=#FFFFFF, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
l_Sym04 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym04_bar-1, text = "ETHUSD",   textcolor=#FFFFFF, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
l_Sym05 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym05_bar-1, text = "CGLDUSD",  textcolor=#FFFFFF, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
l_Sym06 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym06_bar-1, text = "ALGOUSD",  textcolor=#FFFFFF, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
```

Comment: Hey, as per my best knowledge, I don't think you can do exactly what you have in mind.
A workaround is that you use the tradingview alerts function.
Use 'for loops' or hardcode symbols to check for conditions in sequence and send alerts.

I think that's the best you're gonna do

Comment: Look at the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66051986/how-to-calculate-only-latest-candle-on-a-screener-script/66091643#66091643). The solution will be similar. If you can't do it yourself, I'll help you.

Comment: Cheers AnyDozer reading now.

Comment: @AnyDozer you assistance will be gratefully appreciated, I have looked at the above link and this one https://uk.tradingview.com/script/j96rBWfD-ORB-Indicator/ and cant get my head around it.

Comment: Please provide a full working script for the changes.

Comment: @AnyDozer please see an update above. I have been working on it but just don't seem to be getting it right. Your support/assistance will be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study(title="Help (Panel Wave Trend & MF)", shorttitle="Panel Wave Trend & MF")

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// USER Symbol Input

Symbol01 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:BTCUSD")
Symbol02 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:LTCUSD")
Symbol03 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:BCHUSD")
Symbol04 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:ETHUSD")
Symbol05 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:CGLDUSD")
Symbol06 = input(title = "Symbol Selection", defval="COINBASE:ALGOUSD")

// User adjustment inputs
offset_val = input(title="Label Offset", type=input.integer, defval=20)
backcolor = input(true, title="Optional background colour Price Action (PA) above or below all IB highs/lows")
DisplayAllIBs = input(false, title="Optional to display all IB highs/lows")
MidLinebackcolor = input(false, title="Optional background colour Price Action (PA) above or below all Midline")

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//TRYING TO IMPLEMENT THE BELOW IB PROCESSES INTO A FUNCTION SO THAT IT CAN USED ACROSS SEVERAL SYMBOLS IN A SCREENER
//The below works out the Initial Balance for Asia, London and New York then plots from the time the IB has finshed its 60 mins.
//It then looks at the 3 IBs to see which IB is the highest and plots it.
//The aim is to plot green on the monitoring panel if the price has gone above the highest IB
//Plot red if price has gone below the lowest IB
//Plot white if it is inbetween the highest and lowest IB

// Start of the function, must include all calculations
IBCALC () =>
    
    // Asia START //
    //////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance Asia Start
    time_int_01 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)
    
    in_time_int_01 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_01)
    
    var highe_01 = 0.0
    var lowe_01  = 10e10
    if in_time_int_01
        if not in_time_int_01[1]  
            highe_01 := high
            lowe_01  := low
        else
            highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
            lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)
    //////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance Asia Finish
    
    //////////////////////////////////// Asia Plot Start
    //High
    AsiaIBHighInput = input('0100-0101:1234567', title="Capture Asia IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in
    
    AsiaIBHigh = time("1", AsiaIBHighInput)
    
    var AsiaIBHighPA = 0.0
    if AsiaIBHigh
        if not AsiaIBHigh[1]
            AsiaIBHighPA := highe_01
    
    // plotAsiaIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBHighPA : na, title=" Asia IB High", color=color.purple, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
    // plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia IB High")
    
    //Low
    AsiaIBLowInput = input('0100-0101:1234567', title="Capture Asia IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in
    
    AsiaIBLow = time("1", AsiaIBLowInput)
    
    var AsiaIBLowPA = 0.0
    if AsiaIBLow
        if not AsiaIBLow[1]
            AsiaIBLowPA := lowe_01
    
    // plotAsiaIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBLowPA : na, title=" Asia IB Low", color=color.purple, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
    // plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? AsiaIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.purple, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Asia IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Asia IB Low")
    //////////////////////////////////// Asia Plot Finish
    // Asia FINISH //
    
    
    
    // London START //
    //////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance London Start
    time_int_02 = input("0800-0900:1234567", "London IB Range", input.session)
    
    in_time_int_02 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_02)
    
    var highe_02 = 0.0
    var lowe_02  = 10e10
    if in_time_int_02
        if not in_time_int_02[1]
            highe_02 := high
            lowe_02  := low
        else
            highe_02 := max(high, highe_02)
            lowe_02  := min(low, lowe_02)
    //////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance London Finsh
    
    //////////////////////////////////// London Plot Start
    //High
    LonIBHighInput = input('0900-0901:1234567', title="Capture London IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in
    
    LonIBHigh = time("1", LonIBHighInput)
    
    var LonIBHighPA = 0.0
    if LonIBHigh
        if not LonIBHigh[1]
            LonIBHighPA := highe_02
    
    // plotLonIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBHighPA : na, title=" Lon IB High", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
    // plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Lon IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Lon IB High")
    
    //Low
    LonIBLowInput = input('0900-0901:1234567', title="Capture London IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in
    
    LonIBLow = time("1", LonIBLowInput)
    
    var LonIBLowPA = 0.0
    if LonIBLow
        if not LonIBLow[1]
            LonIBLowPA := lowe_02
    
    // plotLonIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBLowPA : na, title=" Lon IB Low", color=color.yellow, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
    // plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? LonIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="Lon IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="Lon IB Low")
    //////////////////////////////////// London Plot Finish
    // London FINISH //
    
    
    
    // New York START //
    //////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance New York Start
    time_int_03 = input("1430-1530:1234567", "New York IB Range", input.session)
    
    in_time_int_03 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_03)
    
    var highe_03 = 0.0
    var lowe_03  = 10e10
    if in_time_int_03
        if not in_time_int_03[1]
            highe_03 := high
            lowe_03  := low
        else
            highe_03 := max(high, highe_03)
            lowe_03  := min(low, lowe_03)
    //////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance New York Finish
    
    //////////////////////////////////// New York Plot Start
    //High
    NYIBHighInput = input('1530-1531:1234567', title="Capture New York IB High") //set the opening range you are interested in
    
    NYIBHigh = time("1", NYIBHighInput)
    
    var NYIBHighPA = 0.0
    if NYIBHigh
        if not NYIBHigh[1]
            NYIBHighPA := highe_03
    
    // plotNYIBHigh = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBHighPA : na, title=" New York IB High", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
    // plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBHighPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York IB High", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York IB High")
    
    //Low
    NYIBLowInput = input('1530-1531:1234567', title="Capture New York IB Low") //set the opening range you are interested in
    
    NYIBLow = time("1", NYIBLowInput)
    
    var NYIBLowPA = 0.0
    if NYIBLow
        if not NYIBLow[1]
            NYIBLowPA := lowe_03
    
    // plotNYIBLow = plot(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBLowPA : na, title=" New York IB Low", color=color.blue, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)
    // plotshape(DisplayAllIBs ? NYIBLowPA : na, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="New York IB Low", offset = offset_val, transp=20, title="New York IB Low")
    //////////////////////////////////// New York Plot Finish
    // New York FINISH //
    
    
    // Background colors
    AsiaAboveHigh = close>(AsiaIBHighPA)
    LondonAboveHigh = close>(LonIBHighPA)
    NewYorkAboveHigh = close>(NYIBHighPA)
    
    // IB Highest and Lowest Settings
    Buy = AsiaAboveHigh and LondonAboveHigh and NewYorkAboveHigh
    // bgcolor(Buy and backcolor ? color.green : na, transp=95, title='Check Chart Buy Signal above all IB Highs')
    
    AsiaBelowLow = close<(AsiaIBLowPA)
    LondonBelowLow = close<(LonIBLowPA)
    NewYorkBelowLow = close<(NYIBLowPA)
    
    Sell = AsiaBelowLow and LondonBelowLow and NewYorkBelowLow
    // bgcolor(Sell and backcolor ? color.red : na, transp=95, title='Check Chart Sell Signal below all IB Lows')
    
    
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    //TRYING TO IMPLEMENT THE ABOVE IB PROCESSES INTO A FUNCTION SO THAT IT CAN USED ACROSS SEVERAL SYMBOLS IN A SCREENER
    //The below works out the Initial Balance for Asia, London and New York then plots from the time the IB has finshed its 60 mins.
    //It then looks at the 3 IBs to see which IB is the highest and plots it.
    //The aim is to plot green on the monitoring panel if the price has gone above the highest IB
    //Plot red if price has gone below the lowest IB
    //Plot white if it is inbetween the highest and lowest IB


    // IBCALC () =>
    
    //    AsiaIBTime = input('0000-0100:1234567')
    //    var highe_A = 0.0
    //    var lowe_A  = 10e10
    //    if AsiaIBTime
    //        if not AsiaIBTime[1]
    //            highe_A := high
    //            lowe_A  := low
    //        else
    //            highe_A := max(high, highe_A)
    //            lowe_A  := min(low, lowe_A)




    AboveAllIBs = color.green //#0CAB07 // Dark Green  -> Long
    BelowAllIBs = color.red //#DE071C // Dark Red    -> Short
    InBetween   = color.white //#E1DE14 // Yellow      #000000   #555555
    
    
    // C   = close
    // O   = open
    

    // IBcolor_  = C > O ? C > C[1] ? AboveAllIBs : AboveAllIBs : C < O ? C < C[1] ? BelowAllIBs : BelowAllIBs : InBetween
    IBcolor_  = Buy ? AboveAllIBs : Sell ? BelowAllIBs : InBetween
    
    
    [IBcolor_]


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

[IBcolor_] = IBCALC ()

color_Sym01 = security(Symbol01, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)
color_Sym02 = security(Symbol02, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)
color_Sym03 = security(Symbol03, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)
color_Sym04 = security(Symbol04, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)
color_Sym05 = security(Symbol05, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)
color_Sym06 = security(Symbol06, timeframe.period, IBcolor_)

// === PLOT HISTOGRAM ===

// === Allocate Strategies to Lines ===
Sym01_bar = 6
Sym02_bar = 5
Sym03_bar = 4
Sym04_bar = 3
Sym05_bar = 2
Sym06_bar = 1


// === Plot Signals per Strategy ===
plot(Sym01_bar, title="BTCUSD", color = color_Sym01, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)
plot(Sym02_bar, title="LTCUSD", color = color_Sym02, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)
plot(Sym03_bar, title="BCHUSD", color = color_Sym03, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)
plot(Sym04_bar, title="ETHUSD", color = color_Sym04, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)
plot(Sym05_bar, title="CGLDUSD", color = color_Sym05, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)
plot(Sym06_bar, title="ALGOUSD", color = color_Sym06, transp = 0, style = plot.style_columns)


// === Plot Background lines ===
line0 = hline(0, title="Line 0", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line1 = hline(1, title="Line 1", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line2 = hline(2, title="Line 2", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line3 = hline(3, title="Line 3", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line4 = hline(4, title="Line 4", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line5 = hline(5, title="Line 5", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)
line6 = hline(6, title="Line 6", linestyle=hline.style_dotted, editable = false)


// === Plot Labels ===
chper = time - time[1]
chper := change(chper) > 0 ? chper[1] : chper

var label l_Sym01 = na, var label l_Sym02 = na, var label l_Sym03 = na, var label l_Sym04 = na, var label l_Sym05 = na, var label l_Sym06 = na
label.delete(l_Sym01), label.delete(l_Sym02), label.delete(l_Sym03), label.delete(l_Sym04), label.delete(l_Sym05), label.delete(l_Sym06)

l_Sym01 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym01_bar-1, text = "BTCUSD",   textcolor=#000000, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
l_Sym02 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym02_bar-1, text = "LTCUSD",   textcolor=#000000, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
l_Sym03 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym03_bar-1, text = "BCHUSD",   textcolor=#000000, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
l_Sym04 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym04_bar-1, text = "ETHUSD",   textcolor=#000000, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
l_Sym05 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym05_bar-1, text = "CGLDUSD",  textcolor=#000000, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
l_Sym06 := label.new(x = time + chper * 20, y = Sym06_bar-1, text = "ALGOUSD",  textcolor=#000000, style=label.style_none, xloc = xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small)
```

[image]